# Solving simultaneous equations in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Given $z_1,z_2$ are complex numbers such that sum of their squares is a real number and $$z_1(z_1^2-3z_2^2)=2$$ and $$z_2(3z_1^2-z_2^2)=11.$$
I need to find the value of sum of squares of two complex numbers.

My intuition helped me guess the answer $z_1=2$ and $z_2=1$ but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: I couldn't type it the way as everyone types . Sorry for that

Comment: Suggested knowledge: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @zoli Thanks for help

Comment: If you add $i$ times the second equation to the first, you get $(z_1 + iz_2)^3 = 2+11i$. If you subtract, you get $(z_1 - iz_2)^3 = 2-11i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks